# How to validate if a parameter is missing from the JSON response - laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, controller, request

I am setting refund for payment gateway for my app, where the response has following fields

```
message, refundId, status
```

Response I get from server,

***Scenario 1 :***

```
{"message":"Total refund cannot be greater than the refundable amount.","status":"ERROR"}
```

***Scenario 2:***

```
{"message":"Refund has been initiated.","refundId":5055,"status":"OK"}
```

***Scenario 3:***

```
{"message":"Invalid response."}
```

I am storing the response result in the database if `refundId` is present, Since the `refundId` field is missing my results are incorrect

Error when the Scenario 1 and Scenario 3 shows up :

```
`Undefined index: refundId`
```

**My controller:**

```
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
        // echo $response;
        // echo $data['message'];
        if (!$data['refundId'] == null) {
            RefundHistory::create(
                [
                    'refund_id' => $data['refundId'],
                    'message' => $data['message'],
                    'status' => $data['status']
                ]
            );
            echo true;
        } else {
            echo $data['message'];
        }
```

How can I ignore the `refundId` field from the response JSON

Comment: `if (array_key_exists('refundId', $data))` or `if (isset($data['refundId']))`

Comment: `if ($data['refundId'] !== null) {` move the exclamation

Comment: And to keep it "laravelly" you can use `if(Arr::has($data, 'refundId')`, which is just `array_key_exists`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Instead of you can check with `!empty` condition as below. It'll check `isset` or `!null`

```
if (!empty($data['refundId'])) {
}
```

2) you may directly use `isset` as well

```
if (isset($data['refundId']) && $data['refundId'] != null) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) and not [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) check to bypass the `Undefined index: refundId` issue

```
if (array_key_exists('refundId', $data) && !empty($data['refundId'])) {
  // your code goes here
}
```